# PluginVersionResolutionException in maven

Tags: maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-release-plugin, maven-compiler-plugin

In my system previously C:\Users\abc after changed as C:\Users\xyz now the problem while running the maven with "mvn clean install" it rises exception as **LocalRepositoryNotAccessibleException**,it takes previous path "C:\Users\abc" but its not there in my system bcz i alreay changed to "C:\Users\xyz".And .m2 folder is not there in my C:\Users\xyz path so i explicitly given in settings.xml localrepository location as "C:\Users\xyz.m2\repository" now .m2 localrepository created above problem solved.But now another i faced another problem is i run command "
mvn clean install" it shows "**PluginVersionResolutionException**" but it recognize the correctly C:\Users\xyz but shows this exception.I check the plugin versions in my files correctly i specified.**Please give me the solution and explain why it behaves like this?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This means that you have defined a plugin dependency in your pom without specifing the version of the plugin.
As you have not specify the error message, I give you an example, an let you fix you own bug.

This is an example :

1/ I suppose that I execute the maven command > mvn intall -X

2/ in the console I have the folowing error :

```
[ERROR] Error resolving version for plugin 'org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin' from the repositories ...
org.apache.maven.plugin.version.PluginVersionResolutionException: Error resolving version for plugin 'org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin' from the repositories ...
```

3/ The error seems to be located in "findbugs-maven-plugin" dependency

4/ I go to my pom.xml file, and I search the dependency to the plugin, I will find that I haven't specified the version of the plugin. So I add it and it will be resolved

like this :

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
   <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.5.3</version> ==> I add this line to fix the pb
</plugin>
```